# What's in the last box?

Tags: pattern, visual, knowledge

Complete the pattern below with an answer from the five choices

[image]

Comment: I love your puzzles, but please continue with the grandpa mysteries! :D

Comment: I find it irritating that there is a big dot on the right of Venus and a line segment on the right of Neptune. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next planet is

> E. Venus

because

> The planet's numbers are $2,7,1,8$. These are the digits of $e$, and the next digit is $2$.

Also notice:

> There is a small dot after the first venus. This represents the decimal point. Thanks @malioboro. I believe the small line after Neptune is simply the cursor on the word processor used to generate the image, and carries no significance to the answer.

Comment: I think that is why there is a dot after venus image

Comment: Good one @Riley. But the answer is "e" not E. Because it is "e". LOL

Answer (score 1):

Labelling Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and Neptune as $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,$ and $7$ respectively.

> The pattern is second and second last coupled together $i.e., 2$ and $7$; First and last coupled together $i.e., 1$ and $8$, next would be 3 and 6 so the answer is $Earth.$

Comment: *Hello!* Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Great answer, but ensure to write your answers and explanations in spoiler quotes, in order to not spoil the answer for other users (unless they give up). Take a look at other answers for example. You can initiate a spoiler quote by writing something in front of `>!` (except in comments — we use [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) for that). Also, since you are new and have not asked any questions yet, I suggest that you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), particularly the *Asking* section. Keep it up! :D

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> E. Venus

The pattern is:

> Venus, Uranus, Mercury, Neptune, Venus, Uranus, ...

Comment: _Less is more_, eh?

Answer (score -1):

> A. The planets go from first to last to second-first and etc.

Comment: The first planet is Mercury, not Venus ...

Comment: oh oops sry i accidentaly mixed them around